# How to read Pending status of an excel add-in

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

So we use an add-in called 'Data Transfer Excel Add-In' to import data from an IBMi series directly into spreadsheets. I do this on a regular enough basis that I've created macros to do this process; however, there is no refined macro process to do this. I have done countless hours of research and attempting the instructions on the IBM webpage about creating a biff8 temp spreadsheet and copying data to clipboard and importing it over as a final step, but it wasn't really an effective solution, and it got a little too complicated for my skill level.

With the lack of elegant solutions available, I have resorted to the crude sendkeys method to use shortcuts to access the ribbon manually, and this works surprisingly well (I understand the problems with sendkeys already - used as last resort). This works to solve my initial problem, but whenever I do this, it has to be ran at the end of any code as any coding afterwards will always create problems. So if I try to import a query to cell a5, then move to sheet2 after the import, it will move to sheet2 first and import or sometimes not import at all. I was wondering if there is a way to read the application state similar to application.CalculationState that would apply to add-ins. For some reason, calculation state doesn't register using this method. I have tried application.wait and that doesn't seem to matter, whenever import is used it HAS to be the last thing in the code and I can't get around it.

I put a sample query import code if it helps. I cant attach a screenshot, but after importing a query a popup shows up titled 'IBM i Access Data Transfer' that says "Retrieving information from IBM i. Please wait.... "

code:

```
SendKeys "%x"    'brings up add-ins
SendKeys "r"     'selects add-in option
SendKeys "~"
SendKeys "~"
SendKeys "jplibr/gugmolist"  'types query library and name
SendKeys "~"
SendKeys "~"
SendKeys "~"
SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"   'fixes stupid numlock/sendkeys glitch
```

I've tried:

if application.calculationstate = x1calculating then
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") )
   end if

also used x1pending with no success

Thanks for your help, sorry if this isn't very concise

Comment: Shouldn't you be keep waiting until Calculation completed instead of just one check?

Comment: You can do this with a loop and a couple API calls, but at that point I'm guessing the instructions on the IBM website are going to be a lot clearer and less bug prone than code that waits for a dialog to go away. Do you still have code from your attempts at accessing the add-in directly? I'm guessing that asking a parallel question based on that code would be more productive (and if not, at least present you with different options).

Comment: that one second wait keeps looping until calculation is complete - I'm not sure why this code successfully works, it goes against what I would assume I know but it works

Comment: The attempts I took were IBM settings and involved transfer requests done through our IBMi system, so I didn't really include any of that, was hoping there was a simple setting that I wasn't aware of